# Lua - Execute a Function Stored in a Table

Tags: function, lua, function-pointers, lua-table

I was able to store functions into a table. But now I have no idea of how to invoke them. The final table will have about 100 calls, so if possible, I'd like to invoke them as if in a foreach loop. Thanks!

Here is how the table was defined:

```
game_level_hints = game_level_hints or {}
game_level_hints.levels = {}
game_level_hints.levels["level0"] = function()
    return
    {
        [on_scene("scene0")] =
        {
            talk("hint0"),
            talk("hint1"),
            talk("hint2")
        },
        [on_scene("scene1")] =
        {
            talk("hint0"),
            talk("hint1"),
            talk("hint2")
        }
    }
end
```

Aaand the function definitions:

```
function on_scene(sceneId)
    -- some code
    return sceneId
end

function talk(areaId)
    -- some code
    return areaId
end
```

**EDIT:**

I modified the functions so they'll have a little more context. Basically, they return strings now. **And what I was hoping to happen is that at then end of invoking the functions, I'll have a table (ideally the levels table) containing all these strings.**

Comment: It's not clear how or what you want invoked in the loop. Perhaps you can explain and give pseudo-code. BTW—Lua doesn't have pointers. Functions are values of type `function` and can be used anywhere in expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using what you guys answered and commented, I was able to come up with the following code as a  solution:

```
asd = game_level_hints.levels["level0"]()
```

Now, `asd` contains the area strings I need. Although ideally, I intended to be able to access the data like:

```
asd[1][1]
```

accessing it like:

```
asd["scene0"][1]
```

to retrieve the area data would suffice. I'll just have to work around the keys.

Thanks, guys.

Comment: You probably could do that with metatables, but it is also probably not worth the effort ;)

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: to call a function (reference) stored in an array, you just add `(parameters)`, as you'd normally do:

```
local function func(a,b,c) return a,b,c end
local a = {myfunc = func}
print(a.myfunc(3,4,5)) -- prints 3,4,5
```

In fact, you can simplify this to

```
local a = {myfunc = function(a,b,c) return a,b,c end}
print(a.myfunc(3,4,5)) -- prints 3,4,5
```

Long answer: You don't describe what your expected results are, but what you wrote is likely *not* to do what you expect it to do. Take this fragment:

```
game_level_hints.levels["level0"] = function()
    return
    {
        [on_scene("scene0")] =
        {
            talk("hint0"),
        }
    }
end
```

[*This paragraph no longer applies after the question has been updated*] <s>You reference `on_scene` and `talk` functions, but you don't "store" those functions in the table (since you explicitly referenced them in your question, I presume the question is about *these* functions). You actually *call* these functions and store the values they return (they both return `nil`), so when this fragment is executed, you get "table index is nil" error as you are trying to store `nil` using `nil` as the index.</s>

If you want to call the function you stored in `game_level_hints.levels["level0"]`, you just do `game_level_hints.levels["level0"]()`

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Inside your anonymous function, you're returning a table that uses `on_scene`'s return value as keys. But your `on_scene` doesn't return anything. Same thing for `talk`.

I'm going to assume that you wanted `on_scene` and `talk` to get called when invoking each levels in your `game_level_hints` table.

If so, this is how you can do it:

```
local maxlevel = 99
for i = 0, maxlevel do
  game_level_hints.levels["level" .. i] = function()
    on_scene("scene" .. i)
    talk("hint" .. i)
  end
end
-- ...
for levelname, levelfunc in pairs(game_level_hints.levels) do
  levelfunc()
end
```